# How to remove a user from all ther groups they belong to in django model?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

For instance, I have two model `Group` and `OrganizationUser`. `members` is a field in `Group` model which defines as

```
members=models.ManyToManyField('organizations.OrganizationUser', related_name="member_in_groups", blank=True)
```

that means a `Group` instance can have zero or multiple member and an `OrganizationUser` instance can be a member of zero or multiple Group

For an instance of OrganizationUser `user1` I can do `user1.member_in_groups.all()` to access all the groups `user1` is a member of. I want to remove `user1` from all the groups `user1` is a member of. I'm feeling iterating over the groups one by one and remove `user1` isn't a right approach. What is the right way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have got the solution**

`clear` method should work in the scenario. `user1.member_in_groups.clear()` will clear the record of groups `user1` member of also it will reflect on the other end of the relation, that means `user1` will be removed from the groups `user1` was a member of.